# Need to disable control key and al so the print characters

Tags: 12.04

How can I disable control characters and also printing the control characters?

I used the below code to disable the control characters but its printing  ^C when I press the CTrl + c..I need to disable the printing as well..

```
  1 trap '' 2
  2 echo "This is a test Hit ctrl + c to test it"
  3 sleep 20
  4 trap 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the feature of the terminal you are using, you can disable it with

```
stty -ctlecho
```

After this it won't echo back the control chars. To disable it permanently just add that command to your `~/.bashrc`.